# Append to a list inside of a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am trying to load a JSON file with Python and extract only the necessary data with the following code. Is there any way to accomplish this in a better/simpler way? I feel like this could be done using `defaultdict` in `collections` and without `if` statement but cannot figure out.

```
import json

with open('somedata.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

main_dict = {}

for item in json_data:
    values1_list = item['sub_values1']
    values2_str = item['sub_values2']

    if item['main_key'] in main_dict:
        main_dict[item['main_key']]['sub_key1'].append(values1_list)
    else:
        main_dict['main_key'] = {'sub_key1': values1_list, 'sub_key2': values2_str}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setdefault` method on your main_dict:

```
main_dict = {}
for item in json_data:
    values1_list = item['sub_values1']
    values2_str = item['sub_values2']
    vals = main_dict.setdefault('main_key', {'sub_key1': values1_list, 'sub_key2': values2_str})
    vals['sub_key1'].append(values1_list)
```